# How to convert a string buffer to pdf format in Xamarin froms/ C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have made a get request to view a pdf in xamarin froms. But the content is a string buffer and I don't know how to convert it to a pdf format so i can later view it in my app. I can view pdf´s in two ways, locally and from a url.

This is the content after my get request:

%PDF-1.5
%����
1 0 obj
<>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<>
endobj
3 0 obj
<>/ExtGState<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<>
stream
x�u��
�0F�@���Л�����O��`6qj�S'��J)v�;>8�@�P��/
�,Q55� �:khMl�Rhp<
��O.���np�)��wuR��p��R�1���2�|�����i�p�ǲcyK���x�>�d��lP�}�7�1�
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<>
endobj
6 0 obj
<>
endobj
7 0 obj
<>
endobj
8 0 obj
<>
endobj
9 0 obj
< #4
Thread finished:  #8

And this is my code:

```
public async void getPdfForProduct(String productId)
{
    var baseUrl = "http://";
    var pdfUrl = baseUrl + productId + "/sds";

    try
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri(pdfUrl);
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            validToken = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(validToken);
            cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("access_token", string.Format(validToken)));
            var result = client.GetAsync(pdfUrl).Result;

            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Besides getting the PDF content from the web, I see no attempt to make it a PDF at all

Comment: Thats my problem, i don't know how to make that content in to a pdf. Sorry if i was unclear with that.

Comment: do you know what this content is called? I see it as a string or string buffer

Comment: What happens if you save it to disk? If you don't like strings, read it as byte[] ReadAsByteArrayAsync

Comment: you need to read it as a byte[], not a string.  Then write it to disk and then open it.

Comment: I will try this, its a good ide to save it to disk. But what kind of encoding does it need when i make it to a byte array?

Comment: You don't need to encode it.  Read it directly from your HttpClient as a byte[].

Comment: something like this u mean? : var result = client.GetByteArrayAsync(pdfUrl).Result